# Как избавиться от горизонтальных отступов в GridView?

Tags: java, android, activity, gridview

Имеется таблица с элементами. Столбцы которой отдалены друг от друга. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было убрать отступы между столбцами?

**Вот, где я создаю программно GridView:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.linear);
        context=this;
        createList(28);
        buttonAdapter=new ButtonAdapter(this,R.layout.item,list);
        gridView.setNumColumns(4);
        gridView.setAdapter(buttonAdapter);

        GridView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener=new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                list.get(position).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.but);
                Log.e("Dfsdf",list.get(position).getText().toString());
                buttonAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        };
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

    }
```

**Вот главная разметка XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="neural_networks.bstu.com.myapplication.MainActivity">



        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"></GridView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**А вот разметка содержимого GridView:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"


        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:verticalSpacing="0px" 
android:horizontalSpacing="0px"
```

Comment: пробывал не получилось

Comment: Добавил разметку, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: напишите мне на почту martsinkevych@gmail.com данные для подключения через теамвивер и посмотрю

Comment: Проблема была в фиксированной картинке

Comment: в будущем можно использовать следующий лайфхак - в меню для разработчиков есть пункт "отображать границы" и если его включить то сразу станет видно что именно занимает место.

Comment: Это в андроид студио?

Comment: нет, на самом телефоне